# Per row Shapiro-Wilk test

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I am trying to determine normality for values in rows of a data frame. Ideally, I want to calculate per row Shapiro-Wilk test (as many tests as rows are in the data frame).

The real dataset is big, but for this purpose I am using an example.

```
dput(example)
structure(c(103L, 122L, 40L, 107L, 124L, 108L, 89L, 102L, 40L, 
70L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 133L, 
64L, 55L, 64L, 108L, 124L, 108L, 146L, 13L, 40L, 122L, 124L, 
107L, 122L, 133L, 122L, 107L, 121L, 70L, 113L, NA, 108L, NA, 
40L, 122L, 89L, 36L, 113L, 26L, 26L, NA, 103L, NA, 55L, 153L, 
146L, 36L, NA, NA, 77L, NA, 133L, NA, 36L, 167L, 92L, 65L, NA, 
NA, 40L, NA, 107L, NA, 89L, 146L, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 10:9, .Dimnames = list(
    c("7", "10", "51", "62", "4", "5", "79", "16", "17", "243"
    ), c("centroid", "n_1", "n_2", "n_3", "n_4", "n_5", "n_6", 
    "n_7", "n_8")))
```

As said, I would like to test normality for each row and I predict some rows will "pass" and for others normality won't be calculated because there are not enough values or they are all identical. I am actually very interested in these since I am trying to prove this is a bad idea.
I would like my results to get written into a new column and if normality test cannot be calculated an error message will appear (something ERROR/FALSE)

[image]

I can calculate Shapiro for any row like this:

```
shapiro.test(example[1,])
    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  example[1, ]
W = 0.9631, p-value = 0.7984
```

And I should be able to calculate per row Shapiro like this (not working):

```
> apply(example, example[1:10,], shapiro.test) 
Error in d[-MARGIN] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I hope someone can point me towards the right direction.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function for getting your desired result:

```
df <- structure(c(103L, 122L, 40L, 107L, 124L, 108L, 89L, 102L, 40L, 
                  70L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 133L, 
                  64L, 55L, 64L, 108L, 124L, 108L, 146L, 13L, 40L, 122L, 124L, 
                  107L, 122L, 133L, 122L, 107L, 121L, 70L, 113L, NA, 108L, NA, 
                  40L, 122L, 89L, 36L, 113L, 26L, 26L, NA, 103L, NA, 55L, 153L, 
                  146L, 36L, NA, NA, 77L, NA, 133L, NA, 36L, 167L, 92L, 65L, NA, 
                  NA, 40L, NA, 107L, NA, 89L, 146L, NA, 92L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
                  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = 10:9, .Dimnames = list(
                    c("7", "10", "51", "62", "4", "5", "79", "16", "17", "243"
                    ), c("centroid", "n_1", "n_2", "n_3", "n_4", "n_5", "n_6", 
                         "n_7", "n_8")))

f.shapiro.stat <- function(x, n_diff_numbers = 3) {
  res <- ifelse(sum(!is.na(unique(x))) < n_diff_numbers, 'ERROR', shapiro.test(x)$statistic)
  return(res)
}

res <- apply(df, 1, f.shapiro.stat, n_diff_numbers = 3)

df2 <- as.data.frame(df)
df2$shapiro <- res
df2
> df2
    centroid n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4 n_5 n_6 n_7 n_8   shapiro
7        103  78 133 122  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.9630974
10       122  78  64 124 108 103 133 107  NA 0.9225951
51        40  78  55 107  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.9723459
62       107  78  64 122  40  55  36  89  NA 0.9552869
4        124  64 108 133 122 153 167 146  NA 0.9385053
5        108  64 124 122  89 146  92  NA  NA 0.9809580
79        89  64 108 107  36  36  65  92  NA 0.8915689
16       102  50 146 121 113  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.9307804
17        40  50  13  70  26  NA  NA  NA  NA 0.9911093
243       70  50  40 113  26  77  40  NA  NA 0.9238762
```

The function also checks if there is enough variation in your data.
Example:

```
> f.shapiro.stat(x = rep(1,1,1))
[1] "ERROR"
```

Comment: Thanks, this really works. But isn't the first row suppose to have a number instead of NA?  ```shapiro.test(df[1,])
 p-value = 0.7984```

Comment: No, because there are 5 NAs in the first row, which is more than 4 (which is checked in the function). I edited the function, such that you'll get an error if all the numbers in a row are equal.

Comment: okay,  I see, 
I forgot to explain that NA should just be ignored (biological data)
Normality should only be tested in the real numbers in the row. But because sometimes there are only 2 numbers per row this should result in an error.

Comment: If the missing numbers are represented by `NA` you can make a change in the line `ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) > n_NAs, NA, shapiro.test(x)$statistic)` to `ifelse(sum(is.na(x)) > n_NAs, "ERROR", shapiro.test(x)$statistic)` and you'll get 'ERROR' instead of NA.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it gives me an error in the first column when it shouldn't. I do not care of NAs. If there are at least 3 different numbers I expect a pvalue. Otherwise if less than 3 or they are all the same I expect ERROR. Like in the little made up example. Sorry it I was unclear.

Comment: Thanks! It really works. Already tried with the big datasets and its perfect.

Comment: I have just realised Is printing the W so I changed it to make it print the p.value
shapiro.test(x)$p.value

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
apply(example[1:10,], 1, shapiro.test)
```

The "1" in the middle is the dimension you're applying the function over.
1 for row, 2 for column.

Comment: you are right. Thanks ! I still have problems because of the NA's and the similar numbers. But you are right about that. Thanks!